# Add null to int column

Tags: scala

I have a scala code as below

```
case class Employee(firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, salary: Int)
val employee = new Employee("John", null, "john-doe@some.edu", null)
```

It fails with the below error

```
error: an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion
```

How do i add Null to int salary column?

Comment: `Int` cannot be `null` because it doesn't inherit from `AnyRef` (whereas `String` does). Good Scala practice discourages use of `null`. Use `Option[String]` and `Option[Int]` instead.

Comment: Option[Int] works when we are putting null but when we are giving the value it is failing `case class Employee(firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, salary: Option[Int])
val employee = new Employee("John", null, "john-doe@some.edu", 1)` `error: found   : Int(1)
 required: Option[Int]`

Comment: `Employee("Jo", None, "jd@email.com", Some(1))` It's a `case class` so  you don't need the `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Int is a primitive type and extends AnyVal which cannot hold null.
null can only be used by AnyRef types.

For Int, null translates to 0.

Refer:

```scala
scala> null.asInstanceOf[Int]
res0: Int = 0

scala> null.asInstanceOf[String]
res1: String = null
```

You could instantiate your class as below:

```scala
scala> val employee = new Employee("John", null, "john-doe@some.edu", null.asInstanceOf[Int])
employee: Employee = Employee(John,null,john-doe@some.edu,0)
```